# Refreshing JQuery selectors when dynamic elements are being added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, refresh

In the next code I make a call to a php script using AJAX and then I update `#inner_div` with the JSON response. Along with this, a `#gimme_moar` button was injected into `#inner_div` so I added the click handler to ask more results.

As a result we will call the same PHP script again using ajax, again, and then we will APPPEND the JSON response to `#tabla` which is part of `#inner_div`.

Everything works as expected but 1 thing... `$(".faulty_selector")`is working on the first 50 "rows"... if I keep adding "rows" they won't be tied up with `$(".faulty_selector")` and if I add this handler again it will duplicate itself having at the end as many executions of `$(".faulty_selector")` as we clicked the `#gimme_moar` button.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: URL,
data: {
    data1: '1',
    data2: 2,
    data3: 3
},
dataType: "json",
timeout: 25000,
success: function (data) {
    var counter = 50;
    $('#inner_div').html(data.answer);
    $(".faulty_selector").on('click', function () {
        myfunction_action(this.id);
    });
    $("#gimme_moar").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "URL",
            data: {
                data1: '1',
                data2: 2,
                data3: 3
            },
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 25000,
            success: function (data) {
                counter = counter + 50;
                $('#tabla').append(data.datos);
            }
        });
    }
    });
```

According to a lot of ppl, live() or on() should be able to handle this situation without any problems... but at this point I'm using on('clic', etc etc) and it ain't working...

Is there any way to refresh / rebind the 50 new `$(".faulty_selector")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Delegate the event**

Change

```
$(".faulty_selector").on('click', function() { myfunction_action(this.id); });
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', ".faulty_selector",  function() { myfunction_action(this.id); });
```

**And move the click event to outside** of the `ajax` method. Otherwise you will be binding the same event for event ajax request being sent.

Also seems to be missing the closing braces for `ajax`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    data: {
        data1: '1',
        data2: 2,
        data3: 3
    },
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 25000,
    success: function (data) {
        var counter = 50;
        $('#inner_div').html(data.answer);
    }
});

$(document).on('click', ".faulty_selector", function () {
    myfunction_action(this.id);
});
$(document).on('click', "#gimme_moar", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "URL",
        data: {
            data1: '1',
            data2: 2,
            data3: 3
        },
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 25000,
        success: function (data) {
            counter = counter + 50;
            $('#tabla').append(data.datos);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, though I feel it like an "expensive" solution.

My script is still beign called more than once when I "refresh" or call the first script, so I'll try to narrow my scopes even more.

Thanks a lot @Sushanth

Comment: This is lot cleaner than assigning a click event for every row item. here you bind the event only once.  If you feel it like an expensive solution, try binding the event to `the closest static ancestor of the elements instead of the document`

Comment: @SolracRagnarockradio.. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: oh, the brackets... sorry about that, I rewrote the code on the fly, the original code is a bit more complicated.

At the end I bond the he event to the closest static ancestor which is beign destroyed and re-builded on every new call... Now is working like a charm :D

Thanks a lot for helping me go thru this brain fart xD